# How to restrict access to AWS Load Balancer so only another specific AWS Load Balancer can have Inbound access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-elb

we currently have an API and website running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, both with load balancers.
Right now we are trying to figure out how to restrict all incoming traffic to the API Load Balancer so the Website load balancer is the only point of access to the API.
We have tried to work with the security groups but we can never hit it right.

We have already removed all Inbound access to the API and that restricted all access but we just can't get the Website to access it.

Our finale goal is to have a system where the API can never be reached from the outside but the Website has fully access to it through HTTPS calls.

Hope you guys can help us, thank you in advance!

Comment: SG is the right way in this setup. What have you tried so far?

Comment: We tried to delete all of the standard entries Inbound had in the API Load Balancer and added the Load Balancer SG of the website as the only inbound entry in the SG of the API LB. But now nothing has access to the API not even the website.

Comment: Neither Classic ELBs nor Application Load Balancers can cascade behind another Classic or ALB, so I am inclined to believe that the description of your setup is incomplete.  You newer mentioned how the web site balancer was accessing the API balancer, before you changed that, and which change you made that prevented it from working.

Answer (score 1):

Your website is running on an EC2 instance, which is only accessible through the ELB. The API server runs in a private subnet and accessible through an internal ELB. You want your website to access the API server. The following steps should solve the issues you are facing:

1. Configure your API load balancer as internal, so it is not accessible out of your VPC.
2. Apply the following security group rules to let application instance access the API server.

> **WebApp (EC2) SG**
>
> 80/443  sg-xxxelb (External ELB SG)
>
> **External ELB SG**
>
> 80/443 0.0.0.0/0

Your API server should only be accessible by the WebApp Instance.

> **Internal (API Server) ELB SG**
>
> 443 sg-xxxec2 (The SG of the WebApp EC2 instance).